# how to get hover removed automatically after some time in d3js

Tags: html, jquery, d3.js, mouseover

I have a d3js pie chart with different sections. Each section,if you put mouse pointer on it, it will show custom hover data.

whenever I take mouse pointer outside that section hover is still there until I refresh the page.
I used mouseout function but with that when I take pointer outside, it will remove hover data immediately.

I want to get hover data removed after a specific time like 10 seconds automatically. How to achieve it?
Below is my code i used for mouseover and mouseout.

In code below 1st line in mouseout:

"d3.select("#" + _this.tooltipId).classed("crd3Hidden", true);"
If I write true at last hover data will be there until I refresh. For false it wont show hover data if pointer is outside pie section

```
    paths.on("mouseover", function(d){
        d3.select("#" + _this.tooltipId)
        .style("left", (d3.event.clientX + window.scrollX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.clientY + window.scrollY) + "px")
            .select("#value")
            .html(_this.config.tooltip(d.data, _this.config.label));
        d3.select("#" + _this.tooltipId).classed("crd3Hidden", false);
        var endAngle = d.endAngle + 0.05;
        var startAngle = d.startAngle - 0.05;
        var arcOver = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius)
        .outerRadius(outerRadius + 0.8).endAngle(endAngle).startAngle(startAngle);
        this.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(this.parentNode);//the path group is on the top with in its parent group
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        d3.select(this)
          .style("stroke", "black")//#5eecfd
          .style("opacity", 10)
          .attr("d", arcOver)
          .style("stroke-width", "4px");
    })
    paths.on("mouseout", function(d){
        d3.select("#" + _this.tooltipId).classed("crd3Hidden", true);        
        var endAngle = d.endAngle;
        var startAngle = d.startAngle;
        var arc1 = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius)
        .outerRadius(outerRadius).endAngle(endAngle).startAngle(startAngle);
        d3.select(this)
          .style("stroke", "#145A32")
          .style("opacity", 1)
          .attr("d", arc1)
          .style("stroke-width", "2px");
    });
```

Comment: I answered that to your original question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62872218/how-get-close-iconx-on-hover-on-mouseover-in-d3-js/62901229#62901229

Comment: Thanks Lennart for answering.
when I use it in my code, its working. But suppose my timeout is set to 10s then, no hover is coming after 10s on any pie sections.I needed to refresh page to get hover again.